# Django Use ModelForm to Filter database and return objects to Folium Map and table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a page with a Model Form, a Folium map, and a table. I want the users to be able to query the Django Model through the Model Form and have the results appear on the map and table. I am stuck trying to figure out how to use the form to query the model and how to pass the data to the map and table views. Here is my code so far.

views.py

```
import folium
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import StLouisCityLandTax
from .forms import StLouisCityLandTaxForm


def formViewPage(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = StLouisCityLandTaxForm(request.get)
        if form.is_valid():
            sale = form.cleaned_data['sale']
            neighborho = form.cleaned_data['neighborho']
            properties = StLouisCityLandTax.objects.filter(sale=sale, neighborho=neighborho)
        else:
            properties = StLouisCityLandTax.objects.all()
    else:
        form = StLouisCityLandTaxForm()
        properties = StLouisCityLandTax.objects.all()

    context = {'form': form, 'properties': properties}

    return render(request, 'maps/partials/_form.html', context)


def allObjectsMap(request):
    properties = StLouisCityLandTax.objects.all()

    # create a Folium map centered on St Louis
    m = folium.Map(location=[38.627003, -90.199402], zoom_start=11)

    # add tile layer control and tile layer
    folium.TileLayer(
        tiles='https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        attr='Esri',
        name='Esri Satellite',
        overlay=False,
        control=True
    ).add_to(m)
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

    # add markers to the map for each station
    for i in properties:
        coordinates = (i.point_y, i.point_x)
        # folium.Marker(coordinates).add_to(m)
        iframe = folium.IFrame(
            f"Land tax ID: {i.land_id}" + '<br>' + f"Owner: {i.owner}" + '<br>' + f"Address: {i.address}" + '<br>' +
            f"Total: {i.total}" + '<br>' + f"<a href = https://dynamic.stlouis-mo.gov/citydata/newdesign/data.cfm?Handle={i.handle} target = _blank > Geo St.Louis Link </a>" + '<br>' + {i.address})
        popup = folium.Popup(iframe, min_width=300, max_width=300)
        folium.Marker(coordinates, popup=popup, icon=folium.Icon(prefix='fa', icon='circle', color='blue')).add_to(m)

    context = {'map': m._repr_html_()}

    return render(request, 'maps/partials/_map.html', context)


def tableObjects(request):


    return render(request, 'maps/partials/_table.html')


def combinedView(request):
    form = formViewPage(request)
    m = allObjectsMap(request)
    table = tableObjects(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'map': m._repr_html_(),
    }
    return render(request, 'maps/StLouisCityLandTaxSale.html', context)
```